# Upload video to S3 using pre-signed URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to upload `mp4` video file using s3 pre-signed URL. The video is getting uploaded properly but when I download the same video and play the video, it does not play.

Here is how I did it

```js
// generating pre-signed url
const getSingedUrlforPut = async (bucketName, filename) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: filename,
    Expires: 60 * 5,
    ContentType: "video/mp4",
  };
  try {
    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
    return url
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error generating s3 url ", err)
    throw err
  }
}
```

```js
// uploading it ot s3
  const url = await getSingedUrlforPut(buckets.toConvertCoursesVideos, fileId)
  try {
// file is mp4 file uploaded using form-data
    const resp = await axios.put(url, file})
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you able to download the file but you can't play it?

Comment: Yes I could download it but cannot play it.

Comment: @rajivtv - Have you tried ContentType: 'application/octet-stream' instead of video/mp4